# Referencing a RegEx Variable

Tags: python, regex, string, variables

I'm using python to loop through a large list of self reported locations to try to match them to their home states.  The RegEx expression I'm using is:

```
/^"[^\s]+,\s*([a-zA-Z]{2})"$/
```

Basically, I'm trying to find a pattern that looks like `XXXCITYXXX, [Statecode]`, where *statecode* is only two letters.

My issue is that I don't know how to reference the varying state code once I find a matching string.  I know in Perl that I could use:

```
$state = uc($1)
```

However, I don't know the equivalent Python syntax.  Anyone know?

Comment: Just look at some [basic examples online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm). For example you want to invoke the `search` method, and access `group` on the returned match object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with re.search, which returns a `match` object (if the regex matches at all) with a `groups` property containing the captured groups:

```
import re
match = re.search('^[^\s]+,\s*([a-zA-Z]{2})$', my_string)
if match:
    print match.groups()[0]
```

Comment: Tried it, but getting typeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that groups was a method instead of a property — edited my answer.

Comment: Just switched match.groups[0] to match.group() and I'm all set.  Thanks!